# Contacts need restoration!

Tags: contacts, restore

I see in my galaxy s6 edge that my contacts were saved on Sept. 9th. i then factory reset my phone and havent been able to restore the contact list. Everything else, messasges, phone records, and such are there, but not the names that go with the numbers. Ive tried google contacts under Gmail but that hasnt worked out. Any ideas?

thx,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't back up your contacts before you factory reset, they are gone. They will only be on google if you synced them to google. your phone will sync automatically if you allow with the settings for backup and restoring.